# Rigify rotation controls not working as intended

Tags: rigging, armature, transforms, rigify

I developed a character and added a generic rig, previously all controls worked when rotating with shortcut key <kbd>R</kbd> but recently I got an issue when selecting controls and trying to rotate them with the <kbd>R</kbd> key. Only arrow symbols are moving but the controls do not move, it seems to work with W quaternion rotation in the *Transform* panel however.

Any idea what could be causing this?